# Oracle - in select query, get XMLType to chars?

Tags: oracle, xmltype

Oracle query question here.

I have a table with an XML Type row.

```
REQUEST_XML_DOC_TXT XMLTYPE
```

I want to write a select query that simply returns that as a string.

`select REQUEST_XML_DOC_TXT from mytable`

But when I run this from a java program, it returns it as `XMLType` object. Which I don't want.

How can I adjust my select query to return text instead of an XMLType object?

From [Convert XmlType into CLOB in Oracle Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751650/convert-xmltype-into-clob-in-oracle-stored-procedure) I tried

`select xmlelement(REQUEST_XML_DOC_TXT).toClobVal() from mytable`

but this just returns: `<REQUEST_XML_DOC_TXT></REQUEST_XML_DOC_TXT>`

Note: I have this working if I use Oracle's java jars that provide XMLType object. But I wanted to just rely on ojdbc6.jar to avoid those extra jars.

Comment: `select t.REQUEST_XML_DOC_TXT.toClobVal() from mytable t`

Comment: get(xxx)Val are deprecated. Use xmlserialize insted.
`select  xmlserialize(document t.REQUEST_XML_DOC_TXT as clob) from mytable t`